# TCP Resets when using psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, python, network

I'm trying to do a simple health check for keepalived and other services via a python script and **psycopg2** library. All seems to be alright, until I close the connection, at which point a packet with TCP reset is sent.

Due to frequency and amount of services using **psycopg2** in our environment, this has become very problematic and creates extensive noise in monitoring.

**Script**

```
import psycopg2
import sys


def check():
    # Relying on .pgpass for password
    con = psycopg2.connect('user=monitoring dbname=postgres host=127.0.0.1')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select 'keepalived healthcheck'")
    cur.close()
    con.close()

try:
    check()
    print("ok")
except Exception as e:
    print("not ok")
    print(str(e))
    sys.exit(1)
```

**tcpdump**
`tcpdump -v 'tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-rst) != 0' -ilo`

```
16:27:45.307006 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8123, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    localhost.40797 > localhost.postgres: Flags [R], cksum 0x0cca (correct), seq 3830516781, win 0, length 0
```

From PG side of things, all seems to be OK

```
2019-04-23 16:27:45.300 CEST process=15615 c= t=0 s=5cbf20e1.3cff [unknown]@127.0.0.1:[unknown] app=[unknown] LOG:  connection received: host=127.0.0.1 port=40797
2019-04-23 16:27:45.304 CEST process=15615 c=authentication t=0 s=5cbf20e1.3cff monitoring@127.0.0.1:postgres app=[unknown] LOG:  connection authorized: user=monitoring database=postgres SSL enabled (protocol=TLSv1.2, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, compression=off)
2019-04-23 16:27:45.306 CEST process=15615 c=BEGIN t=0 s=5cbf20e1.3cff monitoring@127.0.0.1:postgres app=[unknown] LOG:  duration: 0.095 ms
2019-04-23 16:27:45.306 CEST process=15615 c=SELECT t=0 s=5cbf20e1.3cff monitoring@127.0.0.1:postgres app=[unknown] LOG:  duration: 0.234 ms
2019-04-23 16:27:45.306 CEST process=15615 c=idle in transaction t=0 s=5cbf20e1.3cff monitoring@127.0.0.1:postgres app=[unknown] LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.006 user=monitoring database=postgres host=127.0.0.1 port=40797
```

I've tried various combinations of OS, psycopg2 and PG versions to no avail.

- **OS**: Centos 7 and Ubuntu 18.04
- **psycopg2**: From latest down to 2.7.x
- **PG**: Latest 11 down to 9.4 (we use 9.4-bdr currently in production)

Has anyone experienced this and could share any advice how I could prevent this from producing network packets with TCP [R] flag ?

Perhaps I'm misusing this library ?

Edit: After further testing and reproducing under different conditions, **this seems to be happening when SSL connection is being used**.

Edit2: To clarify the importance of this problem, this is the two nodes in the cluster and their tcp reset rate. The expectation here is to have very low rate, so appropriate alerts can be set. [image]

If we set up alert thresholds to high values, we may miss out on actual problems in the cluster, i.e. MIT attacks etc.

Comment: For those of us who are DBAs and not network engineers, can you explain why this is a problem?

Comment: I don't know if this will help you, but I see this occur only when connecting over SSL.  It is a property of the underlying libpq library, not specific to psycopg2.

Comment: Hi @jjanes. TCP reset is ungraceful close of connection network conversation, and should not be happening, unless there is some error etc. This is also an issue as in it creates noise in monitoring for any of our postgres instances.

Edit: I will test this without TLS and see, if this makes any difference.

Comment: Why does it create noise? Also, please edit your question so that all these comments can be removed.

Comment: Hello @Colin'tHart, I've updated the question with more clarification, as to why I consider this as a problem. Thanks.

Comment: If related to TLS have you tested different version of the underlying TLS library used, because this will be more the variable, both on client and server side? Is there any firewall or active network elements that can touch packets between the two? Have you the same behavior without explicit `con.close()`?

Comment: Hello @PatrickMevzek, I have not tried it with different TLS related libs specifically. I have tried it with various PG SQL server distributions, however. As to `con.close()`, I've tried with and without, also with autocommit and the behaviour is exactly the same.

Comment: This behaviour is breaking port-forwards in kubectl. See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1169